# Turing machine given the following inputs: 1010

Tags: algorithm, theory, turing-machines

I am studying for exams and I have no idea on how to come up with a turing machine state table given the following inputs 111101 (State, Input/Read, Write, Move, Next State). Any idea where I can get simplified tutorials on turing machines.

Comment: Please rephrase the question; is `111101` an input to the desired Turing machine or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The state table is essentially a program. A representation of how the machine should move between states, depending on what it reads from the tape, and what to write to the tape in the transition. It is often visualised using circles (or something) for states, and arrows for transitions.

So if I understand you correctly, what you are asking is sort of “what should a program look like if the input is 111101?” That doesn't make sense: in order to design a program (state table) you need to know what it should do with the input, and it should probably work on more than one input.

Here is one very short introduction to Turing machines: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/turing-machine/one.html